# Migration to Spring 6 - How can I replace OAuth2RestTemplate.java to get user roles from OAuth?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to migrate an old project from Spring 5.3.X to Spring Boot 3.0.6 and running into an issue with our deprecated OAuth server ( self-built). It's implemented so far that you can't get roles / scopes of the user with the JWT or you can load the roles / scopes from a database - No, you have to call a protected REST endpoint of the OAuth server to get the information. I can still do that with Spring 5.3.x using `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate`. But this class does not exist anymore with Spring Boot 3.0.6. What options do I have now to call the protected REST endpoint of the OAuth server?